# ProcessBuilder shell command redirection

Tags: java, processbuilder

If I run the following:

```
new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "tail -n 10 -F /app/log.txt");
```

I can read the output and it is as I would expect.

If I run the following command in a shell, I get output as I would expect:

```
/bin/bash -c "tail -n 10 -F /app/log.txt | grep -i ERROR"
```

However, if I now add a grep to process builder:

```
new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "tail -n 10 -F /app/log.txt | grep -i ERROR");
```

I get no output, reading it exactly the same way, but I can't figure out why?

Comment: Did you tried with invoking a shell? Like this: `new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "tail -n 10 -F /app/log.txt | grep -i ERROR");` `"/bin/sh"` instead of `"/bin/bash"`

Comment: @Patrick - tried, didn't work - thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It may not be possible to have a Redirect.PIPE from a subpress of the shell, which is how the parts of a pipeline are being executed. Redirect.INHERIT produces the pipeline output on standard output, but you probably want to read it in the Java program.

Comment: It seems that you must create the pipe and run two Process object connected via a pipeline.

Comment: @laune I was hoping that wouldn't be the answer...I was kinda hoping there would be some funny redirection string I could add to the end of the command....

Comment: Tried to code a specific script and run it through ProcessBuilder?